# Is there any advantage to holding on to multiples of mods?

Tags: warframe

Is there any advantage to holding on to multiples of mods instead of selling them? I have a ton of multiples of mods any reason to not sell them apart from holding onto each fusion level for lower level guns? Do I need to have multiple mods to apply them to multiple configs/guns?

If I have a config A on a mk1-bo and I use for example preassure point does the instance of the mod get used up? Can I usethe same instance of preassure point on let's say heat sword?

Comment: you use the multiples to make the card stronger. so a base card may be 5% bonus for something. You fuse the cards and now the bonus is 45%.

Comment: @Barret Not anymore.

Answer (score 5):

There is really only one major advantage to keeping a few multiples of mods.  (I will begin with a note that rare mods can often times have some sort of demand, and--if worth the platinum--are probably better off sold).  Like you mentioned, having some mods at various ranks can be useful.  For example, maybe you can fit a max Vitality on one frame or a max Serration on a primary, but not on another.  Having a few copies of staple mods are good.

However, there is no advantage to keeping large numbers of mods that you don't need/can't sell for plat.  You don't need 200 copies of redirection.  These are best either sold for credits (not recommended), or broken down into Endo (recommended).

Comment: (unless they changed it) Both you and your sentinal cant use the same instance of a mod, so running doubles of some mods are needed.

Comment: @ShadowZ.  I get around that problem by running the sentinel shotgun when I run a rifle primary and vice versa.  I find it far easier than running a full set of two mods for rifle and/or shotgun.